# Sliding two divs at once using JQuery UI while doing css transition

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-transitions, jquery

When clicking on the arrow, I am trying to slide the "#left" div and have the"#arrowTab" div follow it (slide at the same time).
The #arrowTab div shouldn't slide off the screen, but the #left div should.  In other words, when the arrow is clicked the #left div should slide out of view and the #arrowTab div should slide flush to the left side of the screen.  Therefore, when the arrow is clicked again everything can slide back to the right.

Also when clicked I want the arrow to rotate left to right (and vice versa) in an animated fashion.

I tried both relative and fixed positioning for the #arrowTab div but neither worked correctly. With relative positioning it looks like the #arrowTab div jumps and then starts sliding. With fixed positioning it doesn't move at all and then disappears.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/erebel55/S5PaD/7/

CSS:

```
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: purple;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    /*text wrapping*/
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#arrow {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform linear 300ms;
   transition: transform linear 300ms;
}

#arrow.right {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
   transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#arrowTab {
    background-color:limegreen;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    /*left: 20%*/
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
    opacity: .6;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#arrow").click(function() {
        $( "#left" ).toggle( "slide", 1000 ).toggleClass('slid');
        $(this).toggleClass("right");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your arrow tab div lies inside your left div. After the animation slide has ended left disappears (JQuery hides it) and your arrow tab too. Take out the arrow tab, append it after left and it works.

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENTS FROM erebel55:**

Add this to your CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Change your Javascript into this:

```
$("#arrow").click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("right")) {
        $( "#left" ).animate({"left": '0'}).toggleClass('slid');
    } else {
        $( "#left" ).animate({"left": '-20%'}).toggleClass('slid');    
    }

    $(this).toggleClass("right");
});
```

What I did:

I changed your toggle into an animate function of JQuery. Now your #left div moves to the left instead of being shrinked and hidden. Also, I check if your #arrow has a class named 'right'. If true your #left div will be moved to the right otherwise it will be moved to the left. In addition: overflow: hidden 'hides' the moved #left div without making it invisible.

Comment: Sorry, I linked to wrong jsfiddle revision (updated now). That makes sense for fixed positioning. Is it the same issue for relative?

Comment: I put the arrowTab div within the left div because I wanted them to move together. (This is why I set arrowTab's position to left). If I take it out of the left div it doesn't move when left slides.